# Excel Separator point change to decimal places

Tags: excel, format, decimal, separator, vba

I apologize in advance for my english is not perfect.

I have a web query more than 400 value and the data show in table $20.49.
I would like import an other table, but I would like if show the value $20,49.
I tried all cell format, but it is not change.
Column is C3:C459.

I think macro resolve this problem, but I can not write.
I would like change "." ---> ","   (20.49 --> 20,49)
Could you help me?

Comment: Tried Search-Replace? Record a macro while doing that if you want to use VBA

Comment: You didn't mention your version of excel.  This may help if you go the VBA route: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I just found the solution: 

=SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",")+0  

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the **system separators** or make a local change by going to the *Advanced* section of Excel Options, clear **use system separators** and pick your own:

[image]

If you want to change on certain cells in the worksheet, you would need a **macro**

Comment: Thank you, but system separators not working.
I just found the solution:
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",")+0